# How to use SUM () function in a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Example I have the following line of code which returns this error:

**code:**

```
lblPesoItens.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(TempTable.Compute("Sum(ProdPeso)", ""))).ToString();
```

> Invalid use of Sum () function and type aggregation: String c#

Comment: Which class object is TempTable?

Comment: @adamshakhabov an GridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a data table and a column contains int values (correct me if I'm wrong). Try to use Linq :

```
var sum= TempTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Value"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lblPesoItens.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(TempTable.Compute($@"{Sum(ProdPeso)}", ""))).ToString();
```